# freeradius server timeout upon connecting

Tags: timeout, radius

Is there anybody that knows how to the connection timeout of freeradius to something higher than 10 seconds?

I have been searching for ages, but my Softether VPN that authenticated to FreeRadius closes the connection after 10 seconds which dont allow enough time to authenticate doing 2FA.

I have been grepping on "10" and looking into google for several days without luck, hopefully someone else also experienced this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `max_request_time`. See [here](http://networkradius.com/doc/3.0.10/raddb/radiusd.html).

Comment: No ``max_request_time`` only controls the lifetime of a running request.  Because FreeRADIUS <= 3 are blocking, you need to force the server to give up processing after a relatively short period of time so you don't starve out other requests.

This'll be a configuration somewhere in the VPN server, or if he's doing EAP there's a configuration item that sets how long ongoing sessions are allowed to continue for.  If OP confirms he's using EAP i'll dig out the config item.